# How to distribute android from eclipse

Tags: android

I had been a neewbe in android. I developed an app with some tutorial, If works fine in DVM. I would like to get this in my phone and in my friend's mobile. How can i get it in my phone.

Which file from eclipse to disribute.

Thanks in advance for all consideration.

Comment: is there any clean and build ?? any such

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of the distribution is for testing only, you can copy the *.apk from your project's bin folder.

Be careful with that though, the application is signed with your debug key, and if that key changes you will not be able to reinstall the application without deleting the current one (along with it's data) first.

You can either back up your debug key, or generate a proper key to sign your apk (and backup that one). I can't recall the specific documentation regarding that, but I soppose it's somewhere in this page: http://developer.android.com/distribute/index.html

Good luck!

Comment: Or just Project->Export->Android Project (or something like that) and you get a signing wizard including key generation if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to distribute your app, you need to compile it into an apk.

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/publishing_overview.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [`Google USB Driver`](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html). Here's the official [HOW-TO](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver).

That was for running your app directly from eclipse. If you just want to install the app permanently. The installer file is located at the `bin` folder in your project folder.

Comment: In bin file i have my  Clock.apk, shuld i just copy and sent it to my friend